# Modifying specific array elements in Python 3.1

Tags: python, list

I have two arrays: `array` and `least_common` (filter array)

The following code iterates through `array`, checks for elements that match `least_common`, and if finds it, modifies it and appends it to a new array.

```
 for i in range (len(array)):
        for j in range(len(least_common)):
            if array[i] is least_common[j][0]:                
                new_array.append ((array[i]) + (array[i] * (mod[1]/100)))
```

However, if the element in `array` does not match any of the elements in `least_common` I wan't to append it to `new_array`, then iterate to the next element in `array` to begin the checking process again.

Comment: In python, you can/should iterate over list elements by `for a in array:`, since you don't need the indices for anything. Also, you should probably use `==` rather than `is`.

Comment: If a certain answer solved your problem, please accept it(click the outline of a checkmark next to the answer).  You will gain reputation.  Also, if an answer is helpful at all(whether it solves your problem or not) please upvote it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code is a bit wonky to me -- I think you want to start with something more like:

```
lookup = set([x[0] for x in least_common])
new_array = []
for elem in array:
    if elem in lookup:
        new_array.append(elem + (elem * (mod[1]/100)))
    else:
        new_array.append(elem)
```

Answer (score 3):

In Python, what you are trying to do is done using lists. There is another separate data type called arrays, but that is for totally different purpose. Please don't confuse and use the proper terminology, list.

Lists can be iterated through. You need to not index the elements out of the list and then access them using the index. That is C or C++ way of doing things and not python.

You use a list or a dictionary called `mod` in your original code. It is a bad idea to override builtin names. I tried to understand what you are trying, came up with the following code.  Take it further, but before that, I think some beginner tutorials might help you as well.

```
new_array = []
somevalue = 0.001

for elem in array:
   for anotherelem in least_common:
            if elem == anotherelem[0]:
                    new_array.append(elem + (elem * somevalue))
```

Answer (score 1):

Keep track of whether you found a match using a boolean, which you set to `False` before each inner loop and set to `True` within your `if`. After each iteration, if it's still `False` it means you found no matches and should then do your appending.

You should also follow what @Andrew says and iterate over lists using `for a in array:`. If you need the index, use `for i, a in enumerate(array):`. And be aware that `is` is not the same as `==`.

```
new_array = []
for array_item in array:
    found = False
    for least_common_item in least_common:
        if array_item is least_common_item:
            found = True
    if not found:
        new_array.append (array_item * (1 + mod[1]/100))
```

You can also greatly shorten this code using `in` if you meant to use `==` instead of `is`:

```
for array_item in array:
    if array_item not in least_common:
        new_array.append (array_item * (1 + mod[1]/100))
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not this:

```
least_common_set = frozenset(x[0] for x in least_common)
for e in array:
    if e is not in least_common_set:
        new_array.append(e + (e * (mod[1]/100)))
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly your problem, here is a possible solution:

```
for e in array:
    for lc in least_common:
        if e is lc[0]:
            new_array.append(e + e * (md[1] / 100))
            break
    else:
        new_array.append(e)
```

[The `else` clause](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops) in the `for` loop is executed when the loop terminates through exhaustion of the list, but not when the loop is terminated by a `break` statement.

Note that there is no need to use `range` or `len`, in Python you can just iterate on the elements of a sequence without involving indexes - you may use `enumerate` for that, but in this case you don't need to. Also, please don't use built-in names such as `mod` for your variables: here, I have renamed your dictionary `md`.